# I can't find the developer options in my tablet running Android 4.0.3

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, settings, developer-options

I am starting to learn Android develpment and I bought a very cheap Chinese Android Tablet. It came with 4.0.3 and I can't find the developer option under settings!

I think maybe it's the custom ROM it has, does anyone knows how to solve this? Thanks!

PS: I wanted to post pics of the Settings to show that there isnt a Developer option in there...but I cant even do a printscreen with this tablet since it only comes with the power button, and printscreen requires power and volume buttons...this tablet was too cheap I guess...

PS2: In case it helps:

Model Number FS-MG789

Android Version: 4.0.3

Baseband Version: 0.51

Kernel Version: 3.0.8+ spreadwin version 2.4.10(S101_JH_B)

Build Number: nuclear_puppies-eng 4.0.3 iml74k 20120727 test-keys

**EDIT:**

I couldn't install the device on my PC either so I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987097/android-studio-cant-find-my-device) and installed it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390388/unable-to-install-android-usb-driver-on-windows-7-pro-64-bit) (David Kreps answer)...which is basically to add your device's VID/PID manually to the android_winsub.inf (inside the sdk\extras\google\usb_driver folder).

I am using Android Studio, and it doesn't need a manifest with `debugable` added in it and I did a little test and apparently I can debug a code in the device....but still, I don't know the general implications of this no Developer option in the device.

Answer (score 1):

http://m.androidcentral.com/how-get-developer-settings-galaxy-s4

1. Head into the Settings menu. Samsung's done things a little differently and changed the way the settings menu looks, so you'll need to hit the "More" tab, and then get into the Software information.
2. Look for "About device" at the bottom. Tap it.
3. Hop on down to the build number, and tap it seven times. One. Two. Three. Four. Five. Six. You'll get a little prompt saying you're about to unlock the developer settings. Hit that button one final time -- seven! -- and they're unlocked.

Have you tried this? Its really a bit tricky.

Comment: Yes and it's only for the 4.2.2 and mine is 4.0.3